# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException StartIndex cannot be less than zero get On server, on localhost no error

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

I have very strange problem, I'm downloading html from other website (it is not illegal).

```
string img_1 = startHTML.Substring(startHTML.IndexOf("img"));
```

It was working perfect, but suddanly it stop and show this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy) at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex) at

The strange is that on localhost it is still working.

I know what this error mean, and how to handle with it, but this time is totaly different.

```
try
    {

        string img_1 = startHTML.Substring(startHTML.IndexOf("img"));
        img_1 = img_1.Substring(0, img_1.IndexOf("</div>"));

        if (img_1.Contains("<a href="))
        {


        }
        else
        {
            string img_3 = "";
            string img_7 = img_1.Substring(img_1.IndexOf("src="));

            string img_2 = img_7.Substring(0, img_7.IndexOf(".jpg") + 4);
            img_3 = img_2.Substring(img_2.IndexOf("src=\"") + 5);
            img_3 = img_3.Trim();

            lastImage = img_3;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        try
        {
            string img_1 = startHTML.Substring(startHTML.IndexOf("class=\"poster\""));
            img_1 = img_1.Substring(0, img_1.IndexOf("</div>"));

            if (img_1.Contains("<a href="))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                string img_3 = "";
                string img_7 = img_1.Substring(img_1.IndexOf("src="));

                string img_2 = img_7.Substring(0, img_7.IndexOf(".jpg") + 4);
                img_3 = img_2.Substring(img_2.IndexOf("src=\"") + 5);
                img_3 = img_3.Trim();
                lastImage = img_3;
            }

            lblMsg.Text = "NO IMAGE! " + Convert.ToString(ee);
        }
        catch(Exception eeеее)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "NO IMAGE! " + Convert.ToString(eeеее);
        }
    }

    return lastImage;
```

On **localhost** on the first **try**, there is no **catch**. But on the **server** the second **try** have this problem, and it should not go on the second **try**, because the first **try** on localhost execute correct

I've red here and search in google, but didn't found anything. Can be some cultural problem, if it is, can somebody give where to read how to fix it? And is it possible, the **startHTML** string to become empty in second try I've copy the error and paste it on google. I've opened all links on first page. But no one answear my question.

Comment: Well - obviously - `startHTML.IndexOf("img")` does not return a value you can substring over

Comment: Ad: First place to search is site provided by company I work for: https://msdn.microsoft.com. I.e. it is good idea to read about functions you are using (to avoid "lack of research" votes) - in this case [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If that is not enough - make sure to provide links to articles you've read in the question with one-line explanation why it did not explain problem.

Comment: Side note: you probably should not be using strings manipulation to parse HTML, especially if reading documentation is a problem for you. Consider HtmlAgilityPack or similar HTML parser instead as at least you'll not need to deal with all these off-by-one errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answear, I've faced with this error many times, and I know what it mean. I cannot understand why on localhost it is ok, and on the server suddenly stop been ok. Sorry if I didn't wrote the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Ehat this means is that the text that you pass to the search no longer contains the search string, i.e. "img"

To fix this problem, call IndexOf outside the method call, assign its result to a variable, and check it for -1 before using it as an index:

```
var pos = string img_1 = startHTML.IndexOf("img");
if (pos >= 0) {
    string img_1 = startHTML.Substring(Pos);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know what it mean, and the string contains the "img", the problem is some where else. When I execute the code on localhost it is ok, when it is on the server gives this error.